# How to create object of a class in the other and also vice versa in java?

Tags: java

I have designed a GUI which has a jTextArea. I can append text to this very easily in this class. But I would also like to append text to this from methods of other classes.

For this I make the jTextArea public and create an object of that class in the other class. Now I can write to the jTextArea while executing methods in the other classes.

But it turns out that I need a method of the class I created an object in within my GUI class as well. As I do that, StackOverflowError happens. What should I do?

Comment: Pass a reference of the first class into the constructor of the second class, and save the reference. Easy

Comment: I am not a pro at java. Can you please show me how to save the reference...? thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating another instance of JTextArea when you already have one?

Comment: @AmanChhabra , I dont have an instance of JTextArea in the AutomatedActions class which is also in another package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing the `BTDBattlesBot` object with a `new` keyword in `AutomatedActions` class, you can add a parameterized constructor which takes `BTDBattlesBot` object as parameters and initialize the object in this constructor. Something like below

```
  public class AutomatedActions {
    ...............
   private final BTDBattlesBot botWindow = null;

   // Below is the parametrized constructor
   public AutomatedActions(BTDBattlesBot botWindow) {
   botWindow = this.botWindow;
  }

 ..........
```

}

Then in the `BTDBattlesBot` class, while creating the object of `AutomatedActions` class, instead of calling the default constructor, call the newly created parametrized constructor and pass the current object of `BTDBattlesBot` class using `this` keyword. By doing this you should be able to achieve what you want

```
class BTDBattlesBot {
......
AutomatedActions action = new AutomatedActions(this);
......
}
```